# execute javascript code in web app flutter dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I execute JS code in flutter app using library `flutter_js`. It's working on Android/iOS. My code looks like this:

```dart
    String codeToEval = m['visibilityCase'];
    String code = " " +
        " var result =  eval($codeToEval);  " +
        " result ";
    String jsResult = javascriptRuntime.evaluate(code).stringResult;
    bool boolResult = jsResult == "true" ? true : false;
```

But library [flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js) can not be use in Web App. So what is the best alternative library to execute JavaScript code in multiplatform apps (iOS/Android/Web)?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your JS code, but consider porting it to Dart. (Bonus points if it's useful and you post it to pub.dev.)

Answer (score 0):

Use [js.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/js) for web. For example something like this:

```
@JS()
library main;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('console.log') // annotates `log` function to call `console.log`
external void log(dynamic str);

void main() {
  log('Hello world!');
}
```

Comment: and this code will be working both on mobile (Android/iOS) and Web? I need port only this one function: `eval()`